# fwrite() will write to my file, but fread() won't find the information

Tags: c, file, file-io

So in my code I am inputting an array of structures into a file and then saving them there for a different run on the program. In it's current state, the information writes to the file, but fread() isn't picking up the information (something to do with the EOF?). Thanks in advance.

Here is the `fwrite()` block of code

```
if ((fpnew = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file name: %s", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

...

fwrite(books, sizeof(struct NOVEL), numberofbooks, fpnew);
    fclose(fpnew);
```

Here is the `fread()` block of code

```
if ((fpdisplay = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file name: %s", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fread(books, sizeof(struct NOVEL), numberofbooks, fpdisplay);
    fclose(fpdisplay);
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. But you should probably be checking your return values. Can you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Explore [This](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling/)

Comment: Does the structure contain pointers or arrays?  You can't simply write a structure with pointers — you can write a structure if it only contains arrays of `char` (`struct NOVEL { char title[80]; … };`, for example) and not pointers.